# How to change default scrollbar of entire page and merely within a div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am trying to change the default scrollbar of my webpage with the help of  a [tutorial.](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

The issue is,that the scrollbar changes for the content we put inside a particular div tag and not of the entire page.For example in this  [demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/fluid_scrollbar_example.html)  the scrollbar has changed,but not of the enitire page. Can anyone please help me in changing the scrollbar of the entire page and merely a particular block of content

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to apply plugin to the body: `$("body").mCustomScrollbar()`.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov thanks for the idea. But it does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant change the browser scroll bar in most browsers.

You can only have a cusom scroll bar on an element.

To work around this you need to use overflow.

```
html, body {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Thios will disable the default scroll bar and behaviour.

Then you can use a wrapper element around all your content and apply the js to it.